# how to get last session id in module.php in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to get auto-increment id after storing session in session table in zf2 module.php file

following is my code:

```
$session_id = $sessionManager->getId();
```

now what i want:

```
        $session_table = $sm->get('session_table');
        $resultset = $session_table->select(array(
            'id' => $sessionManager->getId()
            ));         
        $row = $resultset->current();   
        $session_last_id = $row['session_id'];
```

in `$session_last_id`, I will get the auto-increment id of the particular session id,

Problem is :

I didn't get auto increment id when the session is created. I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'session_id' cannot be null' in E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php:240 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php(240): PDOStatement->execute() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(291): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute() #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(258): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeInsert(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Insert)) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\module\Equate\Module.php(52): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->insert(Array) #4 [internal function]: Equate\Module->onBootstrap(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #5 E:\xampp\h in E:\xampp\htdocs\equatmedia_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement.php on line 245
```

But once I refresh the page, error removes and I get what i wnat.
Why i should refresh the page..? i want the id without refresh the page and without error.

I need help friends.
Your help will be highly appreciated. Please help me..

Comment: If you want store session to DB you need use `Session Handler` as `DbTableGateway`. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.session.save-handler.html#dbtablegateway